# Which method faster/better - multiple equal or IN? SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to know - which method is faster/better?

```
$string = '';
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    if(!empty($string)){
        $string .= ' OR ';
    }
    $string .= ' `id` = '.$array[$id];
}
```

Or:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$string = implode(', ', $array);
$string = '`id` IN ('.$string.')';
```

In SQL:

```
'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '.$string
```

Comment: depends ENTIRELY on your dbms and its sql parser and query execution engine.

Comment: Using 'IN' will likely be faster than using 'OR'. You can learn how to test this yourself at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-benchmarking.html

Comment: Okay @MarcB, I hope it's exists a global mechanism that says: "*THIS METHOD IS BETTER*". Thank you.

Comment: better for **WHAT**? compiling the query inside the dbms? executing the query? building the query string in your client?

Comment: @TonyCola thank you for your link, I got what I will read now :)

Comment: @MarcB better for execution time ofc. I think it's clear. I want to optimize my code.

Comment: again, optimize WHICH code? the code that builds the sql? or the actual sql? and are you sure you want to waste time on this? there's exactly **NO** point in optimizing a piece of code that executes for ONCE for about 0.001 seconds in an app that runs for 3 days straight.

Comment: Easy brother :) If better solution is `implode()` and `IN()` I will go this way. Otherwise I do `for()` / `foreach()` and equal option. Maybe it was 0.001s, but I like to have clear solutions. I'm pedant, I can't do anything with that :<

Comment: use `IN`.  someone will come behind you and change it if you don't. plus `IN` gives you the ability to add more conditions than `a = b or a = c` string length wise :)

Comment: Oh @JamieD77 - this is good argument :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, the two are identical.

MySQL, however, sorts the `IN` list and uses a binary search.  Hence, `IN` should be faster than multiple equals in MySQL.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) is the reference:

> Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else
>   returns 0. If all values are constants, they are evaluated according
>   to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done
>   using a binary search.

Comment: Oh, binary search is very good. Thank you @GordonLinoff for your answer. :)